# Distance matrix calculation

Tags: matlab, triangular

I hope you will have the right answer to this question, which is rather challanging.

I have two uni-dimensional vectors **Y** and **Z**, which hold the coordinates of `N` grid points located on a square grid. So

```
Ny points along Y
Nz points along Z
N = Ny*Nz
Y = Y[N]; (Y holds N entries)
Z = Z[N]; (Z holds N entries)
```

Now, the goal would be generating the distance matrix `D`, which holds `N*N` entries: so each row of matrix `D` is defined as the **distance** between the **i-th** point on the grid and the remnant **(N - i)** points.

Generally, to compute the whole matrix I would call

```
D = squareform(pdist([Y Z]));
```

or,equivalently,

```
D = pdist2([Y Z],[Y Z]).
```

But, since `D` is a symmetric matrix, I'd like to generate only the `N(N + 1)/2` independent entries and store them into a row-ordered vector `Dd`.

So the question is: how to generate a row-ordered array `Dd` whose entries are defined by the lower triangular terms of matrix `D`? I'd, furthermore, like storing the entries in a column-major order.

I hope the explanation is clear enough.

Comment: @MitchWheat: it has to result into a `[1,N*(N+1)/2]` array, so only `N*(N+1)/2` entries.

Comment: Far simpler (and far faster) to generate the entire matrix, then toss those you don't wish to keep. This is a phantasm, that it could be simpler in MATLAB if you only generate the upper triangle. Unless the amount of memory blows your budget, don't bother with the false optimization.

Comment: @woodchips: well, actually, at "second-hand" I had already thought about that approach, and probably I'll go with that in the end.

Answer (score 0):

As [woodchips](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85109/woodchips) commented, it is simpler and faster to compute the whole matrix and extract the elements you care about. Here's a way to do it:

```
ndx = find(tril(true(size(D))));
Dd = D(ndx);
```

If you absolutely must compute elements of `Dd` without computing matrix `D` first, you probably need a double for loop.

Comment: We do this sort of thing all of the time in Matlab with vectorized calculations. In computer science the concept is known as the [`"space-time tradeoff"`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space–time_tradeoff). If you need to get back a bit of memory at the cost of some performance (especially here where there's only about 50% sparsity), we have `sparse` matrices.